# change combobox dropdown list background color wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i am trying to change the background color of combobox dropdown or the popup containing options that opens when combobox header is clicked.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
</Style>
```

now this peace of code changes the background color of whole combobox . is there a way to keep the color of header transparent and change the color of dropdown ?

**edit:** i am using material design in xaml toolkit for styling

Comment: I see you apply a `MaterialDesignComboBox` style. What toolkit/style set do you use? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @dymanoid yes brother ! i amusing it . but i dont understand what are you asking ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @dymanoid if you are asking about material design style i am using material design in xaml toolkit ! https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Answer (score 2):

One workaround that I've found is to override `MaterialDesignPaper` color in `ComboBox.Resources`:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper" Color="Red"/>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
This took me hours to find!